# Is it possible to call one yacc parser from another to parse specific token substream?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, yacc

Suppose I already have a complete YACC grammar. Let that be C grammar for example. Now I want to create a separate parser for domain-specific language, with simple grammar, except that it still needs to parse complete C type declarations. I wouldn't like to duplicate long rules from the original grammar with associated handling code, but instead would like to call out to the original parser to handle exactly one rule (let's call it "declarator").

If it was a recursive descent parser, there would be a function for each rule, easy to call in. But what about YACC with its implicit stack automaton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, no. Composing LR grammars is not easy, and bison doesn't offer much help.

But all is not lost. Nothing stops you from including the entire grammar (except the `%start` declaration), and just using part of it, except for one little detail: bison will complain about useless productions.

If that's a show-stopper for you, then you can use a trick to make it possible to create a grammar with multiple start rules. In fact, you can create a grammar which lets you specify the start symbol every time you call the parser; it doesn't even have to be baked in. Then you can tuck that into a library and use whichever parser you want.

Of course, this also comes at a cost: the cost is that the parser is bigger than it would otherwise need to be. However, it shouldn't be any slower, or at least not much -- there might be some cache effects -- and the extra size is probably insignificant compared to the rest of your compiler.

The hack is described in the [bison FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Multiple-start_002dsymbols.html) in quite a lot of detail, so I'll just do an outline here: for each start production you want to support, you create one extra production which starts with a pseudo-token (that is, a lexical code which will never be generated by the lexer). For example, you might do the following:

```
%start meta_start
%token START_C START_DSL

meta_start: START_C c_start | START_DSL dsl_start;
```

Now you just have to arrange for the lexer to produce the appropriate START token when it first starts up. There are various ways to do that; the FAQ suggests using a global variable, but if you use a re-entrant flex scanner, you can just put the desired start token in the scanner state (along with a flag which is set when the start token has been sent).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, and went with this way, which so far works nice. I'm not much concerned with speed of parsing, I'm sure that bison smart enough to keep rules in set-like structures and not consider rules not applicable to the current non-terminal. Biggest chore so far gives me the scanner, which thus is shared with C scanner: my DSL has its specific keywords, which pollute C token space. I guess, I'll need to use 2 separate flex scanners eventually.

Comment: @pfalcon, If it were just keywords, then the flex solution is easy; use rules like this: `"dslkeyword" { if (in_dsl) return DSLKEYWORD; else return ID; }`. But that can get ugly; another simple solution is to use start conditions: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Start-Conditions.html